# Thin spaces in set-builder notation

Tags: typography

Knuth recommends inserting thin spaces inside the braces in set-builder notation. I do not quite get the point in doing so. Why would one write `\{a,b,c\}` but on the other hand `\{\,x\mid x>5\,\}`? Is this style well-regarded?

How am I supposed to typeset conditional probabilities using `\mid`, then? `P(X>5\mid1<X<6)` or `P(\,X>5\mid1<X<6\,)`? `P(A\mid B)` or `P(\,A\mid B\,)`?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

One view is that `\mid` has spacing around it and one gets a better balance by adding thin spaces to the enclosing braces.  On the other hand for short conditional probability expressions I would suggest using the tighter `|` instead of `\mid`.  Thus

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\( \{a,b,c\}  \)

\( \{\,x\mid x>5\,\} \)

\( P(\,X>5\mid1<X<6\,) \)

\( P(A|B) \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tend to recommend using a macro for the last case here, as I think this need more space around the |, especially if A or B is complicated. Btw see the \Set example in the mathtools manual